# How to save only polygon features out of a geojson using GDAL?

Tags: gdal

I have some geojsons that contain OSM data with points, lines, and polygons-- how can I extract only the polygon or line features using GDAL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
ogrinfo -dialect SQLite -sql "select * from osm_data where st_geometrytype(geometry)='POLYGON'" osm_data.json
```

Instead of "osm_data" use the layer name that `ogrinfo osm_data.json` shows you. When the test with orginfo is successful use the same SQL in your ogr2ogr command.